# How can I print out the complete function declaration of any function which has a specific string inside it?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, function

I have lots of functions in my `bashrc`, but for newly created ones I often forget the name of the function.

So for example, when I have defined this function in my `.bashrc`:

```
function gitignore-unstaged
{
    ### Description:
    # creates a gitignore file with every file currently not staged/commited.
    # (except the gitingore file itself)
    ### Args: -

    git ls-files --others | grep --invert-match '.gitignore' > ./.gitignore

}
```

And I would like to have another function which prints out the definition of the function like:

```
$ grepfunctions "gitignore"
function gitignore-unstaged
{
    ### Description:
    # creates a gitignore file with every file currently not staged/commited.
    # (except the gitingore file itself)
    ### Args: -

    git ls-files --others | grep --invert-match '.gitignore' > ./.gitignore
}
```

But instead of matching for "gitignore" I want it to match **every** string between `funtction` and `}`, so `$ grepfunctions "###"` and `$ grepfunctions "creates"` should output the exact same thing. That's also the reason, why [declare -f and such don't solve the problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296712/print-out-anything-in-between-function-argument-to-where-argument-is-th).

### What I have tried

- I can't use [grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep/2686705#2686705)
- I know, that `sed -n -e '/gitignore-unstaged/,/^}/p' ~/.bashrc` prints out what i want - but `sed -n -e '/creates/,/^}/p' ~/.bashrc` not. Instead, I receive:

  ```
      # creates a gitignore file with every file currently not staged/commited.
      # (except the gitingore file itself)
      ### Args: -

      git ls-files --others | grep --invert-match '.gitignore' > ./.gitignore
  }
  ```

  The function name and the first `{` are cut out, which is not what I want.

**How can I print out the complete function declaration of any function which has a specific string inside it? Of course, other tools than sed are also allowed.**

Comment: @Theophrastus i guess you mean `type -f functionname` ?. 1) i sometimes don't know the **exact** function name. 2) Sometimes, i don't know **anything** from the function name, just something from the body.

Comment: @Theophrastus i don't have nested functions. I'm completely fine with a parsing approach (using sth like sed or grep or whatever). I just don't know how I could solve this. That means, i don't know how to correctly approach this problem.

Comment: Would you need to match on the comments in the function, or just the code?

Comment: @thrig. also on the comments. Basically **everything** in between the word `function` and the last `}` of this particular function.

Comment: @Theophrastus this doesn't solve my problem. Its the exact same output as my sed partial-solution. You didn't consider the second point of my "What  i have tried" section.

Comment: To clarify, you don't want the function as it has been defined/parsed by your shell, but rather the function as it exists in your .bashrc (noting that comments get stripped out by the parser)

Comment: @JeffSchaller exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that with `zsh`, you can do:

```
 printf '%s() {\n%s\n}\n\n' ${(kv)functions[(R)*gitignore*]}
```

To retrieve the information from the currently defined functions (that doesn't include the comments obviously).

Now, if you want to extract the information from the source file, then you can't do reliably unless you implement a full shell parser.

If you can make some assumption on how your functions are declared, like for instance if you always use that ksh-style function definition, with `function` and `}` at the start of the line, you could do:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'for (/^function .*?^\}$/gms) {
  print if /gitignore/}' ~/.bashrc
```

or to only look in the function body:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'for (/^function .*?^\}$/gms) {
  print if /\{.*gitignore/s}' ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: your first perl solution works - but your second doesn't.  That means, when i execute `perl -l -0777 -ne 'for (/^function .*?^\}$/gms) {print if /\{.*gitignore/}' .dotfiles/zsh/functions.zsh` (i just used .bashrc to simplify my problem), nothing is printed out.

Comment: @toogley. Sorry, forgot the `s` flag so `.` matches on newline. See editt.